# How to correctly check for an element in a xml tree with ElementTree in python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
    <displayMessage>Authentication Error</displayMessage>
    <message>Authentication Error: org.somewhere.auth.AuthenticationException: Invalid username or password
</message>
    <code>2</code>
</error>
```

and I am trying to check if the element `Authentication Error` exists under `error`. But just using the following code

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree


r = requests.get(....)
root = ElementTree.fromstring(r.text)
print(root.findall('error'))
```

it returns an empty list, which I do not understand. I expect to get one element, as there is one `error` element in the xml.

I was about to try something like

```
if len(root.findall('error//Authentication Error'))>0:
    print("auth error")
    ...
```

How to do it right?

Comment: I think `findall` doesn't work because it only looks for children of the element, and `<error>` is the root.

Comment: root itself points to the element Error and if there would be multiple <error> you would certainly got a Parse error because there should be one single root node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because that `error` is `root`.

Try print out `root`:    `<Element 'error' at 0x7f898462ff98>`.

So you can find `displayMessage` and then check its text:

```
any(item.text == "Authentication Error" for item in root.findall("displayMessage"))
```

It will return `True` if there is at least one `Authentication Error`.

Answer (score 1):

find message tag in xmlstring

```
r = requests.get(....)
root = ElementTree.fromstring(r.text)

if len([s.text for s in root.findall(".//message") if 'Authentication Error' in s.text ])>0:
   print("auth error")
   ...
```